# Where do the exact locations of the phone buttons combinations stored?

Tags: boot, system, files

Where do the exact location of the phone button combinations like power reset while holding <kbd>Volume down</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd>, booting to recovery by holding <kbd>Volume up</kbd> + <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> (if there is a Home button) is it on the system, system partition, boot partition, any other partition, etc.

Comment: Your device's primary or secondary bootloader would contain the key combination for booting into special partitions.

Comment: That's what I thought in the first place. But can we modify it?.

Comment: I don't know whether this is possible without having the source code. OEMs don't provide source code for bootloaders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not stored in the Android system, but somewhere in the phone's firmware that's not modifiable.

Such functionalities like hard poweroff or hard reset is controlled by the underlying hardware directly, not by Android system. Therefore the button combos are stored in the hardware controller and are usually not modifiable by software.

Comment: Cool thanks, it would be so cool if you can modify that where you can boot to your recovery in an emergency situation such as hardbricking or some other stuff.

Comment: There usually are internal ports for special rescuing devices to connect